# Missing libmx.dll file in a MATLAB to visualstudio C environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab

I am currently interfacing matlab with visual studio to use in C++. However, I keep getting the errror libmx.dll not found. Navigating to the instructed PATH, I cannot find the libmx.dll fine anywhere. The error tells me that reinstalling the program can help, so I reinstalled matlab and simulink. I still get the same error. I assume that the file was removed because my antivirus thought it was malicious, so how can I obtain another copy of this libmx.dll file?

Comment: According to the Mathworks forum, that file can be found under: MATLABROOT/bin/win32

Comment: It’s highly unlikely that the file was removed by the antivirus. More likely is that you’re looking in the wrong place. I’m any case, you should be using the `mex`  function in MATLAB to compile your program.

Comment: nope, I've looked in that spot. I even allowed hidden file types, and I still couldn't find it there.

Comment: Slight niggle: it should be <MATLABROOT>/bin/win64 on modern systems. What type of interfacing are you doing? Are you trying to build MEX files, or use the Matlab Engine inside your C++ program, or...?

Comment: I'm trying to use the matlab engine inside of a C++ program